# Spinner with several selectable items per row ? (gridview?)

Tags: android, android-spinner

I have a `Spinner` with a lot of items inside, which makes the user scroll too much to find the item he/she wants.

Since items are mainly 4 or 5 letters, I could easily put several per row, like 2 or 3 for a start.

I tried to play with adapters but failed, and I think the logic behind this idea is flawed (1 row == 1 item).

A workaround could be to get rid of the `Spinner` and make a simple button grid dialog, but it seems quite an overkill to me.

How can I make a multicolumn clickable `Spinner` ?

Here are the somehow relevant posts I saw :

- [How to display a two column ListView in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432951/how-to-display-a-two-column-listview-in-android),
  [Multiple Columns on a Spinner?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10902366/multiple-columns-on-a-spinner),
  [MultiColumn List with drop down spinner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13068140/multicolumn-list-with-drop-down-spinner),
  which are not really the problem I face (items in different columns are supposed to be independantly)
- [Items in multiple columns - spinner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19906906/items-in-multiple-columns-spinner)
  which answer doesn't work.
- [Android Spinner items as a grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19972551/android-spinner-items-as-a-grid) which answer is interesting but I cannot understand how to use OP code (gives me a grid of gridviews)

Comment: Instead of spinner, maybe you can go for grid view in a dialog

Comment: As @GeethakrishnaJuluri sad, why not create a fragment who extends DialogFragment, and make the layout look like Grid?

Comment: Yeah that what I said, I could but it seems an overkill. But maybe it's not.

Comment: <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
<Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
<Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
<Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>

Comment: @Akhil Sorry but I have no idea what this could mean. Could you elaborate ?